A problem with obtaining the beam frequencies and mode shapes
I am supposed to find the mode shapes of two assembled beams. To this end, we must reduce the PDE equation of motion of beam to an ODE including the oscillation frequency. The solution of ODE has some exponents that can be obtained as follows:
sol1 = Solve[γ^2 - (399 γ^4)/65 + γ^6 + (
     13 ω^2)/10 - γ^2 ω^2 == 0, γ, 
   Cubics -> True];

The solution is analytical and a bit complicated. Assigning each root to an exponent as:
Table[λ[i] = Flatten[sol1][[i]][[2]], {i, 1, 6}]

the torsion and deflection of a beam can be written as:
ψ[x_][j_] := Sum[c[i][j] Exp[λ[i] x], {i, 1, 6}]
η[x_][j_] := 
 1/(1 + k) (Sum[
    c[i][j] (1/λ[i]^2 - k) Exp[λ[i] x], {i, 1, 6}])

From which the deflection and torsion of each beam can be defined as:
w1[x_] := η[x][1]
w2[x_] := η[x][2]
θ1[x_] := ψ[x][1]
θ2[x_] := ψ[x][2]

We assume two coordinate systems having origins at the left side of each beam. we also that each beam has a length of Pi. Therefore:
s1 = π;
s2 = π;

At this point, we need continuity relations to assemble the beams as:
bcs = Refine[
   Expand[{w1[0] == 0, w1'[0] == 0, θ1[0] == 0, w2[s2] == 0, 
     w2'[s2] == 0, θ2[s2] == 0, w1[s1] == w2[0], 
     w1'[s1] == 
      w2'[0], θ1[s1] == θ2[0], (1 + k) θ1'[s1] + 
       k w1'[s1] - 
       w1'''[s1] == (ρ + k) θ2'[0] + ρ k w2'[0] - 
       w2'''[0], -w1''[s1] + θ1[
        s1] == -w2''[0] + ρ θ2[0], θ1'[s1] + 
       w1'[s1] == θ2'[0] + ρ w2'[0]}]];

To construct the eigenvalue problem and finding the frequencies and mode shapes, one must substitute the relation of the 3rd code box into the above continuity relations and obtain the coefficient matrix of constants vector as:
vec = {c[1][1], c[2][1], c[3][1], c[4][1], c[5][1], c[6][1], c[1][2], 
   c[2][2], c[3][2], c[4][2], c[5][2], c[6][2]};
{rhs, em} = Normal[CoefficientArrays[bcs, vec]];

The matrix em is very complicated. So, its determinant cannot be analytically solved in a short amount of time, specifically in the case of assembling more than two beams.
AS we seek for real valued frequencies (omega), I use the following code for obtaining the frequencies and mode shapes of the system:
ωmin = 0;
ωmax = 10;
stepω = 0.05;

lst1 = Transpose@{Table[
     i, {i, ωmin, ωmax, stepω}], 
    Abs@Table[
      Det[N[em /. ω -> i]], {i, ωmin, ωmax, 
       stepω}]};
lst2 = Transpose@{Table[
     i, {i, ωmin, ωmax, stepω}], 
    Table[0, {i, ωmin, ωmax, stepω}]};

ListPlot[{lst1, lst2}]

f = Interpolation[lst1, InterpolationOrder -> 100];
g = Interpolation[lst2];
freqs = FindRoot[f[x] == g[x], {x, 4}, AccuracyGoal -> Infinity][[
   1]][[2]]

But as you can see, the determinant which have to tend to zero, is very high:
Det[em /. ω -> freqs]

To obtain the mode shapes, the evaluated frequencies should be used in NullSpace as follows:
NullSpace[em /. ω -> freqs]

But it has no solution, due to its sensitivity to the value of frequency.
How can I resolve this?
Best regards

Strange title: ListPlot produces a picture, not a Mathematica expression.
